# Convert Key Code to Key Name

Tags: vb.net, key

I need to convert key codes to the key name (120 to F9 or 71 to G) I can only do this with characters like this. I am getting these key codes from a text document which stores keybinds.

```
Convert.ToChar(reader.ReadLine())
```

But I want it to convert all keys not just letters and I can't figure out how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `System.Windows.Forms` includes a `Keys` enumeration which does just that (`Keys.F9 = 120`)  You could use that for the names, then parse the text read back to the enum value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should cast the integer to the [`System.Windows.Forms.Keys`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.keys(v=vs.110).aspx) enumeration and then use the `Enum.GetName()` function to get the name of the enum as a string:

```
Dim keyCode As Integer = 120
Dim keyName As String = [Enum].GetName(GetType(System.Windows.Forms.Keys), CType(keyCode, System.Windows.Forms.Keys))
```

Comment: Cheers I will try this.

Comment: I'm getting an error on the "Enum" saying "Expression expected" :(

Comment: See the update. ([Enum]). It works now. Forgot the square brackets.